# pshlabel and log graphs: the 10^ disappear

Tags: pstricks

I would like to reduce the label size for all my graphs (using pstricks). I used the following code:

```
\makeatletter
        \def\pst@@@hlabel#1{{\small #1}}
\makeatother
```

which works fine for my normal graphs. But for my Log graphs, the labels become 1,2,3,etc. instead of 10^1,10^2,10^3, etc.

I give a complete minimal example here:

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\makeatletter
\def\pst@@@hlabel#1{{\small #1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pspicture(-1,-1)(5,5)
\psaxes[subticks=5,xylogBase=10,logLines=all](5,5)
\endpspicture\hspace{1cm}

\end{document}
```

---

The vertical labels are \normalsize but correct and the hlabels are \small but incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the font size using `labelFontSize=\scriptstyle` (or if you can use `labelFontSize=\small` if you've set `mathLabel=false`).

To set this option globally, you can use

```
\psset{labelFontSize=\scriptstyle}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset{labelFontSize=\scriptstyle}    

\begin{document}

\pspicture(-1,-1)(5,5)
\psaxes[subticks=5,xylogBase=10,logLines=all](5,5)
\endpspicture\hspace{1cm}

\end{document}
```

---

In PGFPlots, the font of the tick labels can be set using `ticklabel style={font=\small}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log, ymode=log,
    xmin=1, xmax=1e5,
    ymin=1, ymax=1e5,
    grid=both,
    ticklabel style={font=\small}
]
\addplot coordinates {(100,100)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be local but as I said, I would like a global solution. It is true that I could add this to all my psgraphs, but it would be a bit tedious as I have several dozens.

Comment: @anderstood: You can make it global with `\psset{labelFontSize=\scriptstyle}`.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. Maybe this comment should be integrated in the answer but I'm not too sure so I leave it as it is. Accepted!

Comment: @anderstood: You're right, that should go into the answer. I've edited it.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this, but I'm very surprised: both the \psset definition and the option have no effect on the label size... Also, I think you removed the option from your script when you edited it.

Comment: @anderstood: Ah, you're right, I did remove the option accidentally. I fixed that now. But I'm not sure what you mean with they "have no effect on the label size": They do make the tick labels smaller for me.

Comment: My fault: I got mixed up with \scriptstyle and \scriptsize... sorry.